# PHP Array Keys to variables

Tags: php, arrays

I want a value of my array to be displayed if I use a equel or almost equel variable.
So for example if I have the following array line: [1] => g 
I want to display 'g' if I use the variable $1 (Or even better with the varible $arr1, so it does not interfere with other things later on.)

**Here is my code:** (I'm uploading a simple .txt file with some letters and making a array of each individual charachter):

```
$linearray = array();
$workingarray = array();

while(! feof($file)) {

        $line = fgets($file);

        $line = str_split(trim("$line"));
        $linearray = array_merge($linearray, $line);

}

$workingarray[] = $linearray;

print_r($workingarray);
```

When I have done this I will get this outcome;

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => g [1] => g [2] => h [3] => o [4] => n
>   [5] => d [6] => x [7] => s [8] => v [9] => i [10] => s [11] => h [12]
>   => f [13] => g [14] => f [15] => h [16] => m [17] => a [18] => g [19] => i [20] => e [21] => d [22] => h [23] => v [24] => b [25] => v [26] => m [27] => d [28] => o [29] => m [30] => v [31] => b [32] => ) )

I tried using the following to make it work:

```
extract($workingarray);
echo "$1";
```

But that sadly doesn't work. I just recieve this:

> $1

And I want to recieve this:

> g

It would be even better if I recieved the same effect with for example echo "$arr1" and then recieve g and for echo "$arr2" recieve h etc etc

Comment: I don't really get what you are trying to do but variables can't start with a number so `$1` isn't a valid variable name.

Comment: Btw...  `extract()` only works with associative arrays.

Comment: I want to recieve an exact array value if I target it with a variable which is connected to the key (which is connecyed to the value I want to recieve) So [1] => g ---- $var1 and recieve g

Comment: Why not just do: `echo $workingarray[0][1]` or `echo $workingarray[0][2]`? I don't see the benefit of having them as separate variables? If anything, it will get messier.

Comment: Thanks Magnus, I guess I have to do it that way (I tought since my main goal of making this was getting a variable of every charchter in the text file I had a tunnel vision, but your solution will work as good. Thanks.

Comment: You could also remove the line `$workingarray[] = $linearray;` and use  `$linearray` instead. Then you can skip the first [0] and just: `echo $linearray[1];`

Answer (score 3):

This is simply impossible: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

Variable names cannot start with a digit. The only allowable first char for variable names are letters and underscore.

And don't use `extract` or similar constructs. All they do is litter your variable namespace with unpredictable/unknown junk - you could very easily overwrite some OTHER critical variable with this useless junk, making for very difficult/impossible bugs to diagnose.

You're not saving any time by making up these new variables.

Comment: I disagree that you should never use `extract` in your code. It can be very useful for templating and passing variables into views. In fact, Laravel uses exactly that when passing variables to Blade templates. It's true that it can be dangerous and hard to debug especially in this case, but saying it is a useless function is a bit overkill